# Hive import is not compatible with importing into AVRO format

Tags: import, sqoop

I have the following codes:

```
  sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/export \
  --username root \
  --password cloudera \
  --table cust \
  --hive-import \
  --create-hive-table \
  --fields-terminated-by ' '  \
  --hive-table default.cust \
  --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/cust \
  --compression-codec org.apache.org.io.compress.GzipCodec \
  --as-avrodatafile \
  -m 1
```

got the following error, please help.
Hive import is not compatible with importing into AVRO format.

Comment: Hi, can you paste your cust table sample data. and error log?

Comment: Hive doesn't support avro file format import from sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Sqoop does not support to import AVRO format directly into a HIVE table, so as a workaround you can import into HDFS and create a **EXTERNAL TABLE** in HIVE

Step 1 : IMPORT into hdfs

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/export \
>
> --username root --password cloudera 
>   --table cust \
>   --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/cust \
>   --compression-codec org.apache.org.io.compress.GzipCodec \
>   --as-avrodatafile -m 1

This import will create a schema file in the current directory (Linux) with an extension **.avsc** .Copy this file to some location in HDFS (PATH_TO_THE_COPIED_SCHEMA).

Step 2: Create an external table in HIVE like

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cust
>   STORED AS AVRO
>   LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/cust'
>   TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///PATH_TO_THE_COPIED_SCHEMA/cust.avsc');